# UIPath Orchestrator Connection type unavailable for Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Was trying to create an Azure Devops Pipeline for UiPath project using this [link](https://forum.uipath.com/t/uipath-azure-devops-integration/229381), but I am unable to find UIPath Orchestrator Connection type in Service Connection types menu. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To have this connection type available you need to first install [UiPath Integration extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package)

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to add UiPath Integration extension to Azure devops

Comment: You have on the page you linked. :) [Here you are](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package). I replaced link in the reply.

Comment: @RohitChakravorty did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package

install to your current organization and refresh the Azure site and recheck.

it worked for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31130827)